# Google Charts Custom Color Binding

Tags: jquery, svg, google-visualization

Is it possible to bind data to specific colors in Google Charting API...

Suppose i have 2 Pie-Charts as in the [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Qquse/129/)..
I want to bind the Data to specific colors -

eg - EAT should always be RED, SLEEP Should always be GREEN in all the charts...

and if a specific item does not appear in any particular chart then the color corresponding to the missing value should not appear in that chart...

I have tried

```
slices: [{color: 'black', {}, {}, {color: 'red'}]
```

as well as

```
slices: {0: {color: 'black'}, 3: {color: 'red'}}
```

but was not able to handle missing values....

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qquse/129/) to get a clear idea what i am trying to achieve [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Qquse/129/)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup an array of colors that you want to use for each category.  You can fill in an array of colors to use for the current pie chart being drawn based on what is in the pie chart, looping through each item and adding the correlated color.  I set it up in your JSfiddle.  I used generic colors, but you can use any hex colors you want.  I did not account for situations where the category does not have an associated color, so you would need to check for that if that could be an issue.

```
colors = {'Work':'blue',
      'Eat':'red',
      'Commute':'yellow',
      'Watch TV':'green',
      'Sleep':'purple',};

function colorsArray(data){
    var array = [];
    for (var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
        array.push(colors[data[i]['c'][0]['v']]);
    }
    console.log(array)
    return array
}
```

You can check out the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Qquse/130/

Comment: The Solution has stopped working...
It was pretty good for sometime..

But now the solution crashes..

I believe that it is not able to calculate the data.length

Comment: JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference

Comment: I don't know why but the data object getting created by Google changed, a quick fix would be to change the line that says 
colors: colorsArray(data.D') to colors: colorsArray(data.K).
I dont know if this may happen again, or even regularly, I will take a look at the code and see if their is a better way to make it more flexible so it wont break based on something Google may change.

Comment: here is a new fixed version, basically you will want to create the array of chartdata separately, so you can pass it to google, and access it yourself as a reference so you can make a colors array. http://jsfiddle.net/Qquse/140/